# How do I stop ProGuard from removing classes given as parameters to annotations?

Tags: android, annotations, proguard

I have an annotation to set lifecycle listeners on Fragments, but ProGuard strips the classes I give as parameters:

```
@LifecycleListener(listeners = {Listener1.class, Listener2.class})
public class SomeFragment extends LifecycleAnnotationAwareFragment {
    ...
}
```

I know how to tell Proguard not to strip LifecycleListener.class, but not how to tell it to consider the classes mentioned as listeners to be 'needed'.

Is this functionality configurable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there's no support for this in ProGuard at the moment, but by analogy with their approach to annotations handling, the following approach works:

1. Make all the listeners' names match *LifecycleListener
2. Tell ProGuard to keep all such classes

Optionally:

1. Tell the code which adds those listeners to object strenuously if someone tries to add something with a bad name.